# unknown field [dest], parser not found- error coming while reindexing

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, reindex

While indexing with the following code, error arises as unknown field parser not found:

```
client.reindex({

         body: {
            script: {
               source: {
                  index: index,
                  type: "_doc",
                  query: {
                     term: {
                        id: id
                     }
                  }
               },
               dest: {
                  index: dest_ind
               }
            }
         }
      }
```

Comment: `dest` property should be outside of `script`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place `dest` outside and not nested in `script` - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html

```
client.reindex({
    body: {
          source: {
             index: index,
             type: "_doc",
             query: {
                term: {
                   id: id
                }
             }
       },
       dest: {
            index: dest_ind
        }
    }
 })
```

Comment: Yes, but again Some validation error was arising. I removed the script field and rest of the code was as it is. Seems to be working now.

Comment: @A.Code.Ran - I am not really familiar with `reindex`, but the error was about compiler did not knew what is `dest`. So later I checked in the `documentation`.